# OpenLayers GeoServer update an array of features using WFS-T

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I am trying to update features using WFS-T update. I am sending the request from my website (OpenLayers) by passing an array of features.

However, I have noticed that the attributes and geometry of last feature in the array is copied to all other features.

For example, if I pass 5 features to the `writeTransaction` method to update an attribute of all 5 features, it copies the attributes and geometry of the 5th feature to the other features.

```
var clones = []
selectedFeatures.forEach(function (feature) {
    var featureProperties = feature.getProperties();

    delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
    var clone = feature.clone();
    clone.setId(feature.getId());

    clone.setGeometryName('the_geom');

    clone.setProperties({'xyz':'xyz'})

    clones.push(clone)



})
console.log(clones)
transactWFS('update_batch', clones);
```

int the transactWFS method,

```
transactWFS = function (mode, f) {

    var node;
    switch (mode) {
        case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'update_batch':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, f, null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
            break;
    }
    var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);

    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TEST/ows', {
        service: 'WFS',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: payload,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(e) {
            var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
            alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer.<br><br>'
                + errorMsg);
        }
    }).done(function() {
        wfsSource.refresh()

    });
};
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Edit 1 :

XML generated by the request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <Update xmlns:feature="http://192.168.2.38:2020/geoserver/FR_TEST" typeName="feature:streets_freiburg">
      <Property>
         <Name>the_geom</Name>
         <Value>
            <MultiLineString xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="CRS:84">
               <lineStringMember>
                  <LineString srsName="CRS:84">
                     <posList srsDimension="2">7.8173387 47.9757636 7.8177991 47.9756823</posList>
                  </LineString>
               </lineStringMember>
            </MultiLineString>
         </Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Street_Id</Name>
         <Value>2315516</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Src_Str_id</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Full_Name</Name>
         <Value>Marie-Juchacz-Weg</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Class</Name>
         <Value>9</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>One_way</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Extra_Pass</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Length</Name>
         <Value>35.444</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Speed</Name>
         <Value>15</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>DrivingTim</Name>
         <Value>0.1417</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Serv_Area</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>From_Z</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>To_Z</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Width</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Veh_Size</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LPriority</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RPriority</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ZipL</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ZipR</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LComment</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RComment</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LServeTime</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RServeTime</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BServeTime</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LQuantity</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RQuantity</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BQuantity</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LCusts</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RCusts</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BCusts</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LUnits</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RUnits</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BUnits</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LRevenue</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RRevenue</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BRevenue</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LRouteFile</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RRouteFile</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LCycle</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RCycle</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>CycleLegnd</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LFacil</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RFacil</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LFacilCost</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RFacilCost</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LSP</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RSP</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>X_LRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>X_RRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>NetErr</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>NetErr_Ok</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>NetErr_Id</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Up_Date</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>SameSelect</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Serv_Mode</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>WalkingTim</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ARA_BU_L</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ARA_BU_R</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Prefix</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Name</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Type</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Suffix</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>L_F_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>L_T_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>R_F_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>R_T_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RndAb</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Exclude</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_ID</Name>
         <Value>4867063</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_NameL</Name>
         <Value>Marie-Juchacz-Weg</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_NameI</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_RdRef</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_Meta</Name>
         <Value>name=Marie-Juchacz-Weg, highway=service, service=driveway</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Meters</Name>
         <Value>35.444</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Feet</Name>
         <Value>116.286</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_KMH</Name>
         <Value>15</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_MPH</Name>
         <Value>9.32</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_Lanes</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Class</Name>
         <Value>51</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Flags</Name>
         <Value>3</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>PoEdge_id</Name>
         <Value>3760</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>PoEId_Src</Name>
         <Value>3013</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>PoEId_Trg</Name>
         <Value>3014</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Car</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Bike</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Foot</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Area</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
         <FeatureId fid="streets_freiburg.6583" />
      </Filter>
   </Update>
   <Update xmlns:feature="http://192.168.2.38:2020/geoserver/FR_TEST" typeName="feature:streets_freiburg">
      <Property>
         <Name>the_geom</Name>
         <Value>
            <MultiLineString xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="CRS:84">
               <lineStringMember>
                  <LineString srsName="CRS:84">
                     <posList srsDimension="2">7.8173387 47.9757636 7.8173674 47.975843</posList>
                  </LineString>
               </lineStringMember>
            </MultiLineString>
         </Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Street_Id</Name>
         <Value>2315512</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Src_Str_id</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Full_Name</Name>
         <Value>Marie-Juchacz-Weg</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Class</Name>
         <Value>8</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>One_way</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Extra_Pass</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Length</Name>
         <Value>9.083</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Speed</Name>
         <Value>10</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>DrivingTim</Name>
         <Value>0.0544</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Serv_Area</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>From_Z</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>To_Z</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Width</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Veh_Size</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LPriority</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RPriority</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ZipL</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ZipR</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LComment</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RComment</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LServeTime</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RServeTime</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BServeTime</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LQuantity</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RQuantity</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BQuantity</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LCusts</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RCusts</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BCusts</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LUnits</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RUnits</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BUnits</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LRevenue</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RRevenue</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BRevenue</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>BRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LRouteFile</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RRouteFile</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LCycle</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RCycle</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>CycleLegnd</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LFacil</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RFacil</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LFacilCost</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RFacilCost</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>LSP</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RSP</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>X_LRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>X_RRoute</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>NetErr</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>NetErr_Ok</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>NetErr_Id</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Up_Date</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>SameSelect</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Serv_Mode</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>WalkingTim</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ARA_BU_L</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>ARA_BU_R</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Prefix</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Name</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Type</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Suffix</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>L_F_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>L_T_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>R_F_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>R_T_Add</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>RndAb</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Exclude</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_ID</Name>
         <Value>4867059</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_NameL</Name>
         <Value>Marie-Juchacz-Weg</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_NameI</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_RdRef</Name>
         <Value />
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_Meta</Name>
         <Value>cycleway:both=no, highway=living_street, name=Marie-Juchacz-Weg, surface=paving_stones</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Meters</Name>
         <Value>9.083</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Feet</Name>
         <Value>29.801</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_KMH</Name>
         <Value>10</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_MPH</Name>
         <Value>6.213</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>OSM_Lanes</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Class</Name>
         <Value>63</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Flags</Name>
         <Value>7</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>PoEdge_id</Name>
         <Value>3756</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>PoEId_Src</Name>
         <Value>3013</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>PoEId_Trg</Name>
         <Value>3006</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Car</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Bike</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Foot</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
         <Name>Po_Area</Name>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Property>
      <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
         <FeatureId fid="streets_freiburg.6579" />
      </Filter>
   </Update>
</Transaction>
```

Please note that I don't get any errors on the Geoserver console.

None with namespace or type name..

Comment: Can you add the xml generated for the request?

Comment: @cabesuon I have updated the question. Added the xml ..

Comment: One more thing, what is your data store?, what is the ID field?.
Just as a test can you try to change the filter of the generated XML to another field like Street_Id, like this, I think this might be a problem with FeatureId
```
<ogc:Filter>
 <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyName>Street_Id</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>XXX</ogc:Literal>
 </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: @cabesuon Why do you think featureId might be a problem ? I have two different feature Ids.

Comment: @cabesuon and the data store is a shapefile.

Comment: There might be some issues using FID, but is weird that happen with shapefile. In this case Geoserver should use the ObjectID. Have you check the relation of the id with the shapefile?. Did you try the test I suggest you?.

Comment: @cabesuon tbh I am quite new to Geoserver. I tried your test. But I am not sure if I did it right.
I used this : 
<Filter>
       <PropertyIsEqualTo> 
       <PropertyName>Street_Id</PropertyName> <Literal>2312875</Literal> 
       </PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </Filter>
I got this :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression

Comment: A good way of testing and getting examples is using the demos of GeoServer [Demos GeoServer Docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/demos/index.html#demos). BTW your code make sense to me, and again the test I suggest you is just to check if it could be a problem with FeatureId. I am not sure if that is your problem.

Comment: @cabesuon Yes I use the GeoServer Demos interface too. And yes, I am not sure if feature ID is my problem. Thanks anyway.